# Returning Accounts with no recent orders

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to return a list of accounts that have not ordered within 60 days. My data is all orders from the past three years.

I was planning to use a formula that uses SPILL -

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(OrderAmounts[[Account]],OrderAmounts[Invoice Date]<(TODAY())-60,))
```

However, I realized it includes accounts that DO have recent orders because they ALSO have orders that fit that criteria.

So I attempted to use MAX within the FILTER,

=FILTER(OrderAmounts[[Account ]],MAX(OrderAmounts[Invoice Date])<(TODAY())-60,"Oops")

but it's returning "Oops" - no matching data. So I figure I'm misusing the formula somehow.

***Here's an image of my data:***

[image]

Thank you for any time or help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To make your data example useful, kindly post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below formula-

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A11),TODAY()-MAXIFS(B2:B11,A2:A11,UNIQUE(A2:A11))>60,"Oops")
```

[image]