# Adding multiple criteria to FILTER and/or MAXIFS to return accounts with no recent orders

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been looking for a formula that will return accounts that have no recent orders. [I previously asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73888834/19846946) and the answer was perfect.

I tried to add more criteria to only return results for a particular employee and each attempt failed.

I attempted:

```
 =FILTER(UNIQUE(OrderAmounts[[Account ]]),Today()-MAXIFS(OrderAmounts[Invoice Date],OrderAmounts[[Account ]],UNIQUE(OrderAmounts[[Account ]]),OrderAmounts[Name]="Mark")>60,"Oops")
```

I also attempted:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(OrderAmounts[[Account ]]),Today()-MAXIFS(OrderAmounts[Invoice Date],OrderAmounts[[Account ]],UNIQUE(OrderAmounts[[Account ]]))>60*(UNIQUE(OrderAmounts[[Name ]])="Mark"),"Oops")
```

What error am I making? And what's the correct way to add criteria to these formulas?

| Account | Invoice Date | Name |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACC1118 | 1/7/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 3/30/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 5/13/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 6/10/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 6/17/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 6/18/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 6/22/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 6/29/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 7/9/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 7/22/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 8/27/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 9/17/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 9/21/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 10/26/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 11/12/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 11/30/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 1/27/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 2/8/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 2/8/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 3/8/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 3/22/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 3/31/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1118 | 8/19/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 3/31/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 4/29/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 4/30/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 5/12/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 5/26/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 6/9/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4247 | 9/15/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4628 | 6/9/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC4628 | 6/24/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC4628 | 7/14/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC4628 | 7/28/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC4628 | 7/29/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1129 | 4/1/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1129 | 4/1/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1129 | 4/15/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1129 | 5/17/22 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC4246 | 3/31/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4473 | 9/29/21 | Mark |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 5/26/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 6/2/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 6/16/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 6/30/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 7/7/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/2/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/4/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/11/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/16/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/19/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/19/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC1140 | 8/25/22 | Dave |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 9/7/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 9/22/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 9/29/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 10/6/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 11/12/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 11/19/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 12/2/21 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 1/14/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 2/25/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 3/3/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 3/31/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 4/4/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 6/6/22 | Jen |  |  |
| ACC4162 | 5/16/22 | Jen |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the criteria inside `UNIQUE()` function. Try-

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(FILTER(OrderAmounts[Account],OrderAmounts[Name]="Mark")),TODAY()-MAXIFS(OrderAmounts[Invoice Date],OrderAmounts[Account],UNIQUE(FILTER(OrderAmounts[Account],OrderAmounts[Name]="Mark")))>60,"Oops")
```

Use `LET()` function to reduce repetitive use of `UNIQUE(FILTER(...))` functions. Use-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(FILTER(OrderAmounts[Account],OrderAmounts[Name]="Mark")),FILTER(x,TODAY()-MAXIFS(OrderAmounts[Invoice Date],OrderAmounts[Account],x)>60,"Oops"))
```

Comment: If you find the answer helpful and solve your current problem, then you should accept the answer (tick mark it). Your previous question also seems till now open. When you accept a answer that means problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of correcting the formula in the question, I was trying to respond to the requirement:

> a formula that will return accounts that have no recent orders (60 days)... for a particular employee

Here is the formula:

```
=LET(set, FILTER(
  FILTER(OrderAmounts, OrderAmounts[Name]= F2),{1,1,0}), 
  acc, FILTER(set,{1,0}), accUnique, UNIQUE(acc), 
  dates, FILTER(set,{0,1}),
  maxDates, BYROW(accUnique, 
  LAMBDA(row, MAX(FILTER(dates, acc=row)))),
  FILTER(accUnique, maxDates < TODAY() - F4)
)
```

and here is the result:

[image: sample excel file]

Let's explain the statement first in natural language: We need to identify all accounts from Mark which invoice dates are older than `60` days and here would be the steps:

1. Identify Mark's (cell `F2`) unique accounts
2. For all unique accounts identify the most recent invoice dates
3. Select unique accounts which most recent invoice dates that are older than `60` days (cell `F4`)

The above steps are pretty easy to transform into a query language, but unfortunately in Excel we don't have the `QUERY` function as Google Spreadsheet has. Let's see how we can do it with the toolset Excel has.

Identify Mark's accounts and its corresponding invoice date:

```
FILTER(FILTER(OrderAmounts, OrderAmounts[Name]= F2),{1,1,0})
```

The outher filter is just for selecting the columns of our interest: **Account** and **Invoice Date**. We use `LET` function to create all intermediate variables we need. For previous calculation we assign the variable `set`.

From `set` variable, we create additional variables of our interest:

- Mark's accounts: `FILTER(set,{1,0})` named as `acc`
- Mark's unique accounts: `UNIQUE(acc)` named as `accUnique`
- Mark's accounts invoice dates: `FILTER(set,{0,1})` named as `dates`.

Now we have all the elements to calculate the most recent dates from Mark's accounts:

```
BYROW(accUnique, LAMBDA(row, MAX(FILTER(dates, acc=row))))
```

`BYROW` function applies to each `row` (Mark's unique accounts) the `LAMBDA` function. It calculates the most recent invoices dates, via `MAX` function. `FILTER` input argument arrays must have the same size, that is why we use `acc` and filter by Mark's unique accounts (`row = accUnique`).The result is named as `maxDates` The size of this variable is the same as `accUnique` so we can use them in our last filter to only select the unique accounts older than `60` days:

```
FILTER(accUnique, maxDates < TODAY() - F4)
```

Comment: Thank you - but ACC1118 had an invoice on 8/19/2022 (Cell B24 on your sheet) that should exclude itself from the result - that was 42 days ago and I need only ones that have no orders in the past 60 days

Comment: @abrokentenor oh I see I was looking for accounts with older invoices, I need to include the condition and not recent invoices too. I think it is easy to change, let me update it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @abrokentenor answer updated, it took me some time, because the approach from my previous version it totally different. Please check it in your real situation for additional validation and let me know. It is a larger formula, but it operates as I explained in the logic of a query statement via `BYROW`. In my opinion this logic is more intuitive and easy to apply to any other similar case. Provided a detail explanation since is based on Excel function that are relatively new.